# Creating a store button to add/remove amount and display amount (Very Basic)

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, button

Seeking assistance with creating add and subtract buttons within a form to add and remove amount of a line of stock.

Similar to:

[image]

I'm new to html and very new to javascript.

```js
function minus(){
 var bCount = parseInt(document.calculateCart.count.value);
 var count = bCount--;
 document.calculateCart.count.value = count;
  }
function minus(){
 var bCount = parseInt(document.calculateCart.count.value);
 var count = bCount++;
 document.calculateCart.bCount.value = count;
}
```

```html
<div class="productForm">
  <form name="calculateCart" action="#">
   <div class="+-Buttons">
    Quantity <br>
  <input type="button" value="-" onClick="minus()">
  <input type="int" name="count" value=0>
  <input type="button" value="+" onClick="add()">
   </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: <input type="number" min="0" step="1" placeholder="0">

Comment: First of all, rename the second function from Minus to Add

Comment: two typos, `minus` function twice, and `bCount -> count`, bCount doesn't hold the `count` element, it holds some number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to chane your number using buttons and using text-input, you can change your code to that:

```
<div class="productForm">
    <form name="calculateCart" action="https://titan.csit.rmit.edu.au/~e54061/wp/processing.php">
        <div class="+-Buttons">
            Quantity <br>
            <input type="button" value="-" onClick="minus()">
            <input type="number" name="count" value=0>
            <input type="button" value="+" onClick="add()">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    function minus(){
        document.calculateCart.count.value = --document.calculateCart.count.value;
    }

    function add(){
        document.calculateCart.count.value = ++document.calculateCart.count.value;
    }
</script>
```

In HTML don't exist type of input - int, you need to use number or text.

If you want change value only using the buttons, you can make it like this:

```
<div class="productForm">
    <form name="calculateCart" action="https://titan.csit.rmit.edu.au/~e54061/wp/processing.php">
        <div class="+-Buttons">
            Quantity <br>
            <input type="button" value="-" onClick="minus()">
            <span id="your-number">0</span>
            <input type="button" value="+" onClick="add()">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    var a = 0;

    function minus(){
        a -= 1;
        document.getElementById('your-number').innerHTML = a;
    }

    function add(){
        a += 1;
        document.getElementById('your-number').innerHTML = a;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you a heap! This worked exactly as intended. If I would be greedy, is there a way to do the second code snippet while setting a minimum value? Or is this only possible with input tags and not span tags?

Comment: if you want to set the minimum value, you can check it in javascript using if statement.
Something like this:
`if(a < 0) {}` set some styles for button that make minus action, for example make button disabled

Comment: Thanks. I greatly appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

Your both functions are named 'minus'. One of them (the second one) should be 'add'.

Comment: Thankyou, just copy pasted to save time, will be sure to double check in future

Answer (score -1):

- you have s sort of a typo in your code: your function for adding valus is called minus(). So you have two functions with the same name
- I believe you are getting the value of count in a wrong way. You should assign an id to the input and use getElementById

working code:

```js
function minus(){
        var bCount = document.getElementById('count').value;
        bCount--;
        document.getElementById('count').value = bCount;
   document.getElementById('count');
      }
    function add(){
        var bCount = document.getElementById('count').value;
        bCount++;
        document.getElementById('count').value = bCount;
   document.getElementById('count');
    }
```

```html
<div class="productForm">
  <form name="calculateCart" action="https://titan.csit.rmit.edu.au/~e54061/wp/processing.php">
      <div class="+-Buttons">
          Quantity <br>
        <input type="button" value="-" onClick="minus()">
        <input type="int" name="count" id="count" value=0>
        <input type="button" value="+" onClick="add()">
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you can access forms on the document using `document[formName]`, that isn't an issue (in itself), however there is another typo `bCount -> count`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `document.getElementById` in order to get old textbox value.

Please check below code:

```js
function minus(){
 var oldVal = parseInt(document.getElementById("myVal").value); 
 oldVal--;
 document.getElementById("myVal").value = oldVal;

  }
function add(){
 var oldVal = parseInt(document.getElementById("myVal").value); 
 oldVal++;
 document.getElementById("myVal").value = oldVal;
}
```

```html
<div class="productForm">
  <form name="calculateCart" action="https://titan.csit.rmit.edu.au/~e54061/wp/processing.php">
   <div class="+-Buttons">
    Quantity <br>
  <input type="button" value="-" onClick="minus()">
  <input type="text" id="myVal" name="count" value="0">
  <input type="button" value="+" onClick="add()">
   </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. you have two function `minus`, one of them must be `add`
2. if you want use attributre `name` to select, you need to use something look like:

   document.getElementsByName("count")[0].tagName